# Relationship Type "name" as Drupal [Rules] Token in Civicrm Entity module

Tags: drupal, relationships, tokens, civicrm-entity, drupal-rules

Is it possible to retrieve Relationship Type Name in addition to an ID as Rules Token  in Drupal 7? It would add some value to "Create/Edit Relationship" Rules action: we could use it in emails, like "Hello mr. Dow, congrats, you're Organizaton Boss of The Company now" instead of "Mr. Dow, you are [Relationship ID] of The Company". I'd like to provide a patch for [civicrm_entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_entity) but not sure where to start from. Any advise, please?

*Cross-posted here: https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_entity/issues/2986112*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that **Fetch CiviCRM entity by property** action loads anything else but ID, so, in order to get a full Relationship Type, one may want to use  another action with almost the same name has been used ( **Fetch entity by id**) which loads Relationship Type by its ID from any Relationship.